# Where does qemu-img store images and how can i delete them?

Tags: qemu

I remember making an image that I never used. I cannot uninstall qemu-img because I have one vm that is being used.

Comment: qemu-img stores images at the place where you have specified. You can find and delete all images manually

Comment: I don't remember specifying a location, but I found the file in my home folder, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

`qemu-img` stores images in current working directory by default. You can specify any target directory and file name.

So, try to remember the work directory location where you had created those images with `qemu-img`.

Other option is search probable locatios for the extension of image file you use e.g. search for `*.vdi` in your home directory etc.

Then you can easily manually delete them.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't remember the work directory location, you can do a thorough search with the find command, taking into consideration all [qemu-img supported image types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images).

One option:

```
# find / -type f -name *.raw -o -name *.cloop -o -name *.cow -o -name *.qcow -o -name *.qcow2 -o -name *.vmdk -o -name *.vdi -o -name *.vhdx -o -name *.vpc
```

Another option, using -regex:

```
# find / -type f -regex '.*\.\(raw\|cloop\|cow\|qcow\|qcow2\|vmdk\|vdi\|vhdx\|vpc\)'
```